# count relationship in microsoft project

Tags: ms-project, primavera

I am exporting a  ms xml from Primavera P6 and importing it in MS Project. I know the number of relationships in Primavera. But I am not sure if all the relationships are getting imported it MSP. Can anyone please tell a way to find the number of relationship in a MS Project .
Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - if you run the following code on your project, it will produce a dialogue box stating how many dependencies have been defined in the project:

```
Sub CountDependencies()

Dim i_RelationshipCount As Integer
Dim tsk As Task
Dim tsk_dep As TaskDependency

i_RelationshipCount = 0

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If tsk Is Nothing Then GoTo NextTask
    For Each tsk_dep In tsk.TaskDependencies
       'only count predecessors (otherwsie will count each realtionship twice)
        If tsk_dep.To = tsk Then
            i_RelationshipCount = i_RelationshipCount + 1
        End If
    Next tsk_dep
NextTask:
Next tsk

MsgBox i_RelationshipCount & " dependencies/relationships exist in this schedule."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

@AndrewEversight's answer is totally correct. FWIW: Here's a smaller routine to give you the same result:

```
Sub CountDependencies()

Dim i_RelationshipCount As Integer
Dim tsk As Task

i_RelationshipCount = 0

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not tsk Is Nothing Then
         i_RelationshipCount = i_RelationshipCount + tsk.PredecessorTasks.Count
    End If
Next tsk

MsgBox i_RelationshipCount & " dependencies/relationships exist in this schedule."

End Sub
```